# MATLAB Figures and Global Scope

Tags: matlab, global-variables

I am using functions from a MATLAB package ("EEGLAB"). One of the functions I'm using ("pop_selectcomp") creates a GUI. However, when I try to interact with the GUI, an error results: an expected variable (In this case "EEG", a data structure) is not defined. That's odd, because pop_selectcomp has EEG as an input. I discovered that declaring global EEG anywhere in the function stack above my call to pop_selectcomp makes EEG available to it again. This is the structure of my function stack.

- Main Script

  - data import function loads variable "EEG"
  - function to process data

    - function call to pop_selectcomp

So declaring EEG as a global in the main script or the data processing function fixes the problem.

My interpretation is that when pop_selectcomp creates its GUI window, it's being created outside of my function stack in the main workspace or something like that. So, the EEG variable is only available to it if it's been declared global above the function call. I'm not very familiar with Matlab figures and GUIs, but I guess that normally pop_selectcomps doesn't have this problem because it's not called as a sub-function.

Is there any better way to make this work? Can I somehow point pop_selectcomps' GUI at the correct sub-workspace where it will find the variables it needs? I can modify pop_selectcomps if I have to, although that would be messier. The function can be found here:

https://sccn.ucsd.edu/svn/software/eeglab/functions/popfunc/pop_selectcomps.m

Comment: Instead of declaring EEG as a global, build your "function to process data", to take EEG as input argument. See [Create Functions in Files](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-functions-in-files.html). `pop_selectcomps` finds the variables it needs, because your are passing the variables as input arguments to it. Also note, `pop_selectcomps` takes 3 input arguments, and returns 2 output arguments - try to figure out if you need to use them.

Comment: I think I wasn't clear. pop_selectcomps does indeed take EEG as an input argument. But when called from anywhere but the main workspace environment, the GUI window it creates is subsequently unable to find the EEG variable, despite that it was passed - unless the EEG variable is made available to the main workspace, which I'm currently doing through a global. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: The are better alternatives then using global. Read [Share Data Among Callbacks](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/share-data-among-callbacks.html), and